# How to configure embeded mongodb to run in given port in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to use embedded mongoDB with Spring boot for my development and testing. When I try to configure its getting started but always run with dynamic port instead of port which I give in URL config. Idea is I want to use same kind of MongoConfig for both my test (Unit/Integration) and real environment.

My property file looks below.

```
spring:
  profiles: local
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:62309/local_db


@Configuration
public class MongoDBConfig {
    
    private final Environment env;
    
    public MongoDBConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory getMongoFactory() {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.uri"));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(

> getMongoFactory

());
    }

}


pom.xml
--------

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      </dependency>
       
      <dependency>
          <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
          <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
         <!--  <scope>test</scope>  -->
     </dependency>
```

with this configuration app is getting started when I start it but with dynamic port every restart. Also seeing below exception trace in logs. From this seems like Spring is first try to connect given mongo instance from my local machine and its not finding any so its failing then its invoking emebeded mongodb.

Is there a way I can make spring to make use of configured port to run embedded mongoDB without that error being thrown.

### Error Trace

```
[cluster-ClusterId{value='62141aecfb7ede3c51b3d064', description='null'}-localhost:62309] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster -
                Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:62309
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```